# JQuery (django) - Stop blur when form submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, forms

I have a form containing a textarea.
On this textarea there is a blur.
Problem : When I click on submit button, the submit isn't works because there is the blur... :

**THE HTML :**
*(A little of Framework Django in this code but isn't important for this problem : One textarea is in {{ formUpdateSpeciality|bootstrap}} and it's well recuperated by JS ;) )*

```
        <p>The text of speciality</p>
        <form method="POST" id="modifSpec_{{skill.domain|cut:" "}}" name="formUpdateSpecialities" class="form" style="display:none;">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ formUpdateSpeciality|bootstrap }}
            <input type="submit" name="submitSpeciality" class="btn btn-block btn-success" value="Confirm">
        </form>                                                                     
</div>
```

**THE JS** **:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[name=speciality]').click(showForm);
});
```

METHODS **JS** - Show/Hide the form :

```
function showForm(event){

    var form = $(this).find('form');
    $(this).find('p').hide();
    form.show();
    var textarea = $(form).find('textarea');
    textarea.html($(this).find('p').html());
    textarea.focus();
    textarea.blur(hideForm);
}


function hideForm() {
    // ** $(this) => textarea **
    var thediv = $("#speciality_details_CARS");
    var form = $(thediv).find('form');
    form.hide();
    $(thediv).find('p').show();
    thediv.click(showForm);
}
```

**JS** - Form submitted on click on input `<input type="submit" name="submitSpeciality" class="btn btn-block btn-success" value="Confirm">` :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form[name=Theform]").submit(function(evt) {
        alert("hoho");
        evt.preventDefault();
        var speciality = $(this).find('textarea').val();
        var form =  $(this).serialize();
        var data = {
              "formulaire": formulaire,
              "modifi_form" : "update speciality",
        };

        $.ajax({
          'type' : 'POST',
          'dataType' : 'json',
          'url' : "/myurl",
          'data': data,

          success: function(data) {
            alert("success");
          },
          error:function(data){
            alert("Error...");
          }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

So the blur() is in the form textarea.

**Why I can't submit the form ?**

When I click on the submit button, the blur is activated so the form hide and the div show.

Comment: So nobody can help me ?